# Is there an easy way to compare Django's models and migration chain against the db verify consistency?

Tags: django, database, django-south

I've had some migration issues over time and occasionally have run into a case where a field will not have been correctly migrated (almost certainly because I tried some fake migration to get my dev db in a working state).

Doing an automatic schema migration will check the migration chain against the model, but not check either of those against the actual db.

Is there a way to easily compare the database against the current models or migration chain and verify that the db, the models, and migration chain are consistent?

As a straw man imagine you delete your migrations, create a new initial migration, and fake migrate to that initial while deleting the ghost migrations.

Is it trivially possible to verify that the database is in sync with that initial migration?

Comment: How about run a diff between `manage.py sql appname` and an actual dump?

Comment: That's an interesting idea and might work, but would require some more scripting around it. I was hoping such a thing could be done in some simple standard way (i.e. a command with an option or two)

Answer (score 2):

The `django-extensions` application provides `sqldiff` management command, which shows difference between current database and your model. So if there is difference between your database and model (migrations should be same after running `makemigrations` command), you will see.